# When can you use the particle さ?

Tags: particles

I've seen and heard so much the particle さ but I don't get the hang of it. Does it mean anything or make some kind of emphasis? 
Can you use it anywhere in the sentence? Because I've seen it in any position ramdomly (at the beginning, at the end, after the particle は, after a verb, etc.) so I don't know how it works and if it has a different nuance according to its position in the sentence.

Could someone explain it to me?

Thank you so much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It’s difficult to say without seeing what you saw.
What I could guess is a phrase like below.

> おやじがさー、酒好きでさー
>   (My dad likes to drink sake)

In this case, it’s 「さー」or 「さぁ」.
I have never thought about the meaning of the expression. I’d say we usually talk like that when you have negative feeling behind the word - a little complaint, problem or confessing... etc.

Maybe completely different from what you asked. Sorry if that’s the case.

Comment: I don't think this type of さ has negative connotations.

Comment: @naruto Maybe “negative” isn’t best word. But don’t you think some feeling behind the expression? What you you say for that?

Comment: Its role (if any) is to keep the listener's attention. We can easily think of non-negative sentences like "明日さ、どこか行かない?", "それがさ、あいつすごいんだぜ！"

Comment: @naruto なるほど。Don’t know why I could think of only negative situation (>_<;. Thanks for your clarification.